# Need help with alternative method to equation of a tangent at the point of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles

so I know a simpler of looking for the equation of a tangent at the point of a circle is to differentiate, my lecturer would rather we not use calculus and has charged us with looking for an alternate method. Any pointers guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the slope of the line passing through the center of the circle and the point on the circle. Call it $m$. Then form the equation of a line through the point on the circle but let the slope of this line be the opposite reciprocal of the one you just found, i.e. slope $\frac{-1}{m}$.

Comment: Find the equation of the tangent at the point (1, 0)
on the circle x2 +y2 -- 5x -- y + 4 = 0.

Comment: @Tife : make things simple. a circle is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. what you wrote is not yet a circle

Comment: It is a circle, just an expanded form. To get what you're saying, I'll have to solve using completing the square

Comment: I get it now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The tangent line at a point on a circle is perpendicular to the diameter of the circle passing through that point

Also, if a line has slope $s$, another line perpendicular to the first has slope $-1/s$