# Alternative Method To Looking For Equation Of A Tangent And Normal At A Point On A Parabola

Tags: geometry

Like my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1802979/409), I'm looking for an alternate method to calculus in looking for the equation of the tangent and normal at a point on a parabola.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that you know the equation of the parabola, in particular, that you are able to get the coordinates of the vertex $V$ as well as the axis of symmetry $\ell$ for the parabola.

Suppose you want the tangent at point $P$. Given the axis of symmetry, draw the line orthogonal to $\ell$ passing through $P$. Let is intersect the parabola at $P$ and $P'$. Let the midpoint of segment $PP'$ be $M$. Reflect $M$ about $V$ to get the point $N$. Then $PN$ will be the tangent at $P$. Note that this particular construction is a consequence of [Archimedes' Lemma](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ArchimedesTriangle.shtml#lemma).

Given the tangent, you can easily find the normal.